# Piping Rscript gives error after output

Tags: r, unix, pipe

I wrote a small R script to read JSON, which works fine but upon piping with

```
Rscript myscript.R | head
```

the (full, expected) output comes back with an error

```
Error: ignoring SIGPIPE signal
Execution halted
```

Oddly I can't remove this by piping STDERR to `/dev/null` using:

```
Rscript myscript.R | head 2>/dev/null
```

The same error is given... presumably because the error arises within the Rscript command? The suggestion to me is that the output of the head command is all STDOUT.

- Piping STDOUT to `/dev/null` returns only the error message
- Piping STDERR to `/dev/null` returns only the error message...!

Piping the output to cat seems to be 'invisible' - this doesn't cause an error.

```
Rscript myscript.R | cat | head
```

Further pipe chaining is possible after the cat command but it feels like I may be ignoring something important by not addressing the error.

Is there a setting I need to use within the script to permit piping without the error? I'd like to have R scripts at the ready for small tasks as is done with the likes of Python and Perl, and it'd get annoying to always have to add a useless `cat`.

There is discussion of handling this error in C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774569/using-signals-and-sigpipe), but it's not immediately clear to me how this would relate to an R script.

**Edit** In response to @lll's answer, the full script in use (above called as 'myscript.R') is

```
library(RJSONIO)
note.list <- c('abcdefg.json','hijklmn.json')
# unique IDs for markdown notes stored in JSON by Laverna, http://laverna.cc
for (laverna.note in note.list) {
  # note.file <- path.expand(file.path('~/Dropbox/Apps/Laverna/notes',
  #                                   laverna.note))
  # For the purpose of this example run the script in the same
  # directory as the JSON files
  note.file <- path.expand(file.path(getwd(),laverna.note))
  file.conn <- file(note.file)
  suppressWarnings( # warnings re: no terminating newline
    cat(paste0(substr(readLines(file.conn), 2, 15)),'\n') # add said newline
  )
  close(file.conn)
}
```

`Rscript myscript.R` outputs

```
"id":"abcdefg"
"id":"hijklmn"
```

`Rscript myscript.R | head -1` outputs

```
"id":"abcdefg" 
Error: ignoring SIGPIPE signal
Execution halted
```

It's not clear to me what would be terminating 'early' here

**Edit 2** It's replicable with `readLines` so I've removed JSON library-specific details in the example above. Script and dummy JSON gisted [here](https://gist.github.com/lmmx/9bdec10b4307d640fade).

**Edit 3** It seems it may be possible to take command-line arguments *including* pipes and pass them to `pipe()` - I'll try this when I can and resolve the question.

Answer (score 5):

The error is simply caused by an attempt to write to the pipe without a process connected to the other end. In other words, your script has already picked up and left by the time the pipe is reached and the `HEAD` command is called.

The command itself *might not* be the issue; it could be something within the script causing an early termination or race condition before reaching the pipe. Since you're getting full output it may not be that much of a concern, however, masking the error with other `CLI` commands as  mentioned probably isn't the best approach.

---

**The command line solution:**

`R` does have a couple of useful commands for dealing with instances in which you might want the interpreter to wait, or perhaps suppress any errors that would normally be output to stderr.

> For command-line R, error messages written to ‘stderr’ will be sent to
>   the terminal unless `ignore.stderr = TRUE`. They can be captured (in the
>   most likely shells) by:

```
system("some command 2>&1", intern = TRUE)
```

There is also the `wait` argument which could help with keeping the process alive.

> `wait` — logical (not NA) indicating whether the R interpreter should
>   wait for the command to finish, or run it asynchronously. This will be
>   ignored (and the interpreter will always wait) 
>   if `intern = TRUE`.

```
 system("Rscript myscript.R | head 2>&1", intern = TRUE)
```

The above would wait, and output errors, if any are thrown.

```
system("Rscript myscript.R | head", intern = FALSE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
```

The above won't wait, but would suppress errors, if any.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question. I can't see any prematurely-terminating process though. Could you edit your answer to explain 'terminating' (unless it's brief enough for a comment)? The script is a for loop over 2 elements, which are both processed in the output I see, so I don't understand what premature stage this could be.

Comment: It might be the `close(file.conn)` perhaps where things get terminated too quickly. Sometimes this type of behavior is also known also as a [race condition](https://www.google.com/search?q=race+condition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Try commenting out the `close(file.conn)` for a moment and then run the command and see if you encounter the same issue.

Comment: The point is though that I want a script that can be chained to new commands at will. I could take the pipe as an argument within the `system()` call as `system(paste0("Rscript myscript.R | ",args), intern=TRUE)`... but... to pass a pipe in as arguments seems wrong? It would only work for one command (using an actual `|` would end argument reading) so how is a system call able to accept and chain piped output?

Comment: Personally I have no problem using most any standard unix commands within `system`, but it really boils down to what your needs are and how you want to do it. There is a specific front-end you may be interested in called [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler), which is described as: "a simplified command-line interface for GNU R. This allows direct execution of commands, use in piping where the output of one program supplies the input of the next..." - ([more info](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html))

Comment: The docs often seem to illustrate the use of `system`, so maybe they're onto something. I did a quick peek to see if there might be any similar issues to yours and noticed [one in particular that stood out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9534215/499581).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same annoying error.  It appears to be generated from within R by a function writing to STDOUT, if the R function is still running (outputting data to the pipe) when the pipe stops 'listening'.

So, errors can be suppressed by simply wrapping the R output function into `try(...,silent=TRUE)`, or specifically *this* error can be handled by wrapping the R output function into a more-involved `tryCatch(...,error=...)` function.

**Example:**
Here's a script that generates an error when piped:

```
#! /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/rscript
random_matrix=matrix(rnorm(2000),1000)
write.table(x=random_matrix,file="",sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

Output when called from bash and piped to `head`:

```
./myScript.r | head -n 1
-1.69669866833626,-0.463199773124574
Error in write.table(x = random_matrix, file = "", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE,  :
  ignoring SIGPIPE signal
Execution halted
```

**So:** wrap the `write.table` output function into `try` to suppress all errors that occur during output:

```
try(write.table(x=random_matrix,file="",sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE),silent=TRUE)
```

**Or**, more-specific, just suppress the "ignoring SIGPIPE signal" error:

```
tryCatch(write.table(x=random_matrix,file="",sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE),
    error=function(e) if(!grepl("ignoring SIGPIPE signal",e$message))stop(e) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I could overcome this problem by using [`littler`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) instead of `Rscript`:

```sh
r myscript.R | head
```