# How to let Rscript behave similar to other linux programs by not generating errors upon SIGPIPE?

Tags: r, linux, signals, rscript

Here are some related discussions. But I don't think the answers are relevant to my question.

[Piping Rscript gives error after output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915838/piping-rscript-gives-error-after-output)

Normal linux commands work just fine upon receiving SIGPIPE

```
$ seq 10 |head -n 1
1
```

But Rscript behaves differently as shown in the above discussion URL. But littler's r does not have this problem.

Is there a way to make Rscript use the default SIGPIPE handler so that it will have a similar behavior to other linux programs?

Here mentions how to set it a the C level? But is there a way to set so in R code? Thanks.

https://colinfay.me/writing-r-extensions/linking-guis-and-other-front-ends-to-r.html

> You may also want to consider how signals are handled: R sets signal handlers for several signals, including SIGINT, SIGSEGV, SIGPIPE, SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2, but these can all be suppressed by setting the variable R_SignalHandlers (declared in Rinterface.h) to 0.