# Running R + awk from bash

Tags: r

A script run well on R, but failed when it was executed using `R q -e` from bash.

[The script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531648/combining-r-awk-bash-commands) that run well on R was:

```
R> sizes <- read.table(pipe("ls -l /tmp | awk '!/^total/ {print $5}'"))
R> summary(sizes)
```

The command pattern from bash followed [a previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789806/command-line-utility-to-print-statistics-of-numbers-in-linux), but generated error messages:

```
R -q -e "x <- read.table(pipe("ls -l /tmp | awk '!/^total/ {print $5}'"));summary(x)"
awk: line 1: extra ')'
awk: line 1: extra ')'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ;
```

What's wrong with the above command?

```
root@kali:~# uname -a
Linux kali 3.18.0-kali3-586 #1 Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Assuming you are using bash. Your problem is shell quoting. You need to escape the second and third `"` in your command. Like so: `\"`. You could also have used single quotes instead od double quotes, But then you would have had to escape the single quotes surrounding the awk command.

Comment: @Bhas Could you show the correct syntax?

Comment: @Pascal. Probably not. I just tried escaping the inner double quotes. That gave an error message from bash. Escaping the `^` and the `!` does seem to work but R gives an error message: `Error: '\!' is an unrecognized escape ....`.  Not escaping the `!` generates a bash error message: `!/total/: event not found`. So it appears to be quite difficult to get this working. Another solution is required but I haven't got a clue. A real bash expert needs to look into this.

Comment: @Bhas  Yes, I tried also to escape, as you suggested, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`ls -l /tmp | awk '!/^total/ {print $5}' | R --slave -e 'x <- scan(file="stdin"); summary(x)'`

If you're trying to get stats on all the files in a particular directory hierarchy something like this is probably better:

`find /tmp -type f -exec du {} \; | awk '{print $1}' | R --slave -e 'x <- scan(file="stdin"); summary(x)'`